# How to delete array in action script?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a function where I create an array... How to delete it?

Comment: You should take the time and explain a bit more about the specific context in which your question arises, maybe post some example code that allows us to better understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't explicitly delete any objects in ActionScript and you also don't need to. The garbage collector will eventually delete the array for you when it is no loner referenced.

If you are referencing the array from some other place in your program, you can set that var to null in order to remove the reference to the object that you no longer need.